# How to check the element is available in viewport after selecting an element and page refresh using selenium (with in the desktop screen)

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Issue: After selecting an element, refreshing the page, the element is not visible. And after fix, the element is visible without doing any scroll after page refresh. So that I can select a different option.

I tried below and irrespective of element present in viewport (with in visible screen) or not test is passing. I really appreciate if someone could post solution.

```
WebElement element =
> WebDriverManager.getWebDriver().findElement(By.id("CUSTRATINGS"));
> 
>         WebDriver driver = ((RemoteWebElement)element).getWrappedDriver();
> 
>         return (Boolean)((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript(
>                 "var elem = arguments[0],                 " +
>                         "  box = elem.getBoundingClientRect(),    " +
>                         "  cx = box.left + box.width / 2,         " +
>                         "  cy = box.top + box.height / 2,         " +
>                         "  e = document.elementFromPoint(cx, cy); " +
>                         "for (; e; e = e.parentElement) {         " +
>                         "  if (e === elem)                        " +
>                         "    return true;                         " +
>                         "}                                        " +
>                         "return false;                            "
>                 , element);
```

Comment: Are you recapturing your element after the page refresh?

Comment: First I am landing on page and selecting element, then page will refresh. After that I am capturing element to see with in viewport or not.

Comment: Yes, recapturing.

Comment: I think you'd need to check window.innerHeight against the location of the element.  If the document height is larger than window's height then the scrollbar will appear.  Same would be true for width.... use window.innerWidth